# Prometheus Adapter Custom Metrics for Libvirt in a K8S Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, libvirt

I have a K8S cluster which is also managing VMs via virtlet.  This K8S cluster is running K8S v1.13.2, with prometheus and the prometheus-adapter, and a custom-metrics server.  I have written a custom metrics exporter for libvirtd which pulls in VM metrics and have configured prometheus to scrape that exporter for those VM metrics -- this is working and working well.

What I need to do next, is to have the prometheus-adapter push those metrics into K8S.  Nothing I have done is working.  Funny thing is, I can see the metrics in prometheus, but I am unable to present them to the custom metrics API.

**Example metric visible in prometheus:**

```
libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs{app="prometheus-lex",domain="virtlet-c91822c8-5e82-beta-deflect",instance="192.168.2.32:9177",job="kubernetes-pods",kubernetes_namespace="default",kubernetes_pod_name="prometheus-lex-866694b884-9z8v6",name="prometheus-lex",pod_template_hash="866694b884"}
```

**Prometheus Adapter configuration for this metric:**

```
    - seriesQuery: 'libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs{job="kubernetes-pods", app="prometheus-lex"}'
      seriesFilters: []
      resource:
        overrides:
          kubernetes_pod_name:
            resource: pod
          kubernetes_namespace:
            resource: namespace
      name:
        matches: libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs
        as: libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_rate
      metricsQuery: rate(libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs{job="kubernetes-pods", app="prometheus-lex", <<.LabelMatchers>>}[5m])
```

When I query the custom metrics API, I do not see what I am looking for:

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1|grep libvirt

returns nothing
```

Additionally, I can see the prometheus-adapter is able to query the series from prometheus.   So I know that side of the adapter is working.   I am just trying to figure out why it's not presenting them to the custom metrics server.

From the prometheus-adapter

```
I0220 19:12:58.442937       1 api.go:74] GET http://prometheus-server.default.svc.cluster.local:80/api/v1/series?match%5B%5D=libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs%7Bkubernetes_namespace%21%3D%22%22%2Ckubernetes_pod_name%21%3D%22%22%7D&start=1550689948.392 200 OK
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Update::

I have also tried the following new configuration, and it's still not working.

```
- seriesQuery: 'libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs{kubernetes_namespace!="",kubernetes_pod_name!=""}'
  seriesFilters: []
  resource:
    overrides:
      kubernetes_namespace: {resource: "namespace"}
      kubernetes_pod_name: {resource: "pod"}
  name:
    matches: 'libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_nanosecs'
    as: 'libvirt_cpu_stats_cpu_time_rate'
  metricsQuery: 'sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[2m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)'
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how you install the Prometheus Adapter. If you install via helm and use the YAML as configuration to the rules. You need to follow this README https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-adapter/README.md and and declare the rules like

```
rules:
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^some_metric_count$"}'
    resources:
      template: <<.Resource>>
    name:
      matches: ""
      as: "my_custom_metric"
    metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

Pay attention to the custom keyword. If you miss it, the number won't be available via custom metrics.